# Moving files older than 1 hour from one directory to another - AIX

Tags: shell, command-line, aix

I am trying to move files older than one hour, which are being populated almost every minute very rapidly to another folder whose name specifies the particular hour, in aix.

The script i was trying to run is:

```
find /log/traces/ -type f -mmin +59 -exec mv '{}' /Directory \;
```

The above script gives me an error:

> find: bad starting directory

I am a newbie to shell scripting.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

------------------Edited-----------------------

I have been able to move the files older than 1 hour, but if the specified folder does not exist, it creates a file with the name specified in command and dumps all the files in it. The script i am running now is:

```
find /log/traces -type f -mmin +59 -exec mv '{}' /Directory/ABC-$(date +%Y%m%d_%H) \;
```

It creates a file named ABC-[Current hour]. I want to create a directory and move all the files into it.

Comment: Can you output the results for `ls -l /log/traces`

Comment: Does the directory /Directory- (Timestamp) exist before the script exist? May be the directory is not there to move the files.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing I got the command to work and it moves the files to specific folder (if the folder exists already). If the folder does not exist, it just creates a file and dumps all the files in that single file. i.e 'find /log/traces -type f -mmin +59 -exec mv '{}' /Directory/User\;' creates file named user and dumps all the files into that single file. I need to create folder with files of that hour.

Comment: Just add (prepend) `mkdir -p  "/Directory/ABC-$(date +%Y%m%d_%H)";` to the beginning of your current command and it will create the directory if it doesn't exist. (see *man mkdir*)

Comment: Hopefully `$(date +%Y%m%d_%H)` shall be the same between creating the directory and moving the file. I prefer to have a shell script that captures the timestamp in a variable and performs creation and move.

Comment: That is a good point. Better to do `tstamp=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H)` and then `mkdir -p "/Directory/ABC-$tstamp";` then use `$tstamp` at any point later in your script you are currently using `$(date +%Y%m%d_%H)` to make sure the hour doesn't roll to the next between the first time you call `date` and any subsequent calls.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Your point is very valid. What i want to achieve is creating a routine that lets say executes after one hour and dumps all the files created in one specific hour to another folder with name specifying the timestamp i.e date and hour of the files contained in it. If i create a script of what we have come up with, it sounds right to you? Just your opinion

Comment: Yes, what I would do is either make a continual outer loop (e.g. `while : ; do ... done`)  or use `inotifywait` to watch for changes. Then the loop logic could get the `tstamp`, then `mv` files, then `sleep` for the number of seconds desired. You should also include a `trap` on `SIGINT` to catch a `ctrl+c` and do any cleanup required. If the files are coming into the directory as fast as you indicate (many files per minute), I would lean toward the loop `while : ; do ... sleep 60; done` to move a group of files each minute or so (could be 2, 5, 10 minutes). Just what works the best.

Comment: If you think, my suggestions worked. please accept my answer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin after few dry runs, I found out that fetching files with modified time greater than 59 wont do the job for me as i want specific hour files of each day in a specific folder.
What i am thinking is just get the created time upto hour of files whenever the scripts execute, it checks all the files, check their time and creates a folder(if not already created) with the time i fetched from file creation date and dumps

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin what i am trying to do is something like:
'code'istat /log/ABC.txt  | awk '{print $4 $5 $6}' 'code'
It displays something like

**Nov1810:42:31
Nov1810:42:31
Nov1811:33:45**
I am unable to find a way to fetch files of a specific hour and dump them into specific folder of that hour

Comment: Did you get it working? Any answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running as a root user you may be getting this problem because of read permissions on `/log/traces/`.

To see the permission level of this directory run `ls -l /log/traces/` the left most column will display something like this `drwxr-xr-x` which is an explanation of what permission settings that directory has. To understand more read [this](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions).

You need to ensure the user you are executing your command as has read access to `/log/traces/` - that should fix your error.

Comment: I got the command to work and it moves the files to specific folder (if the folder exists already). If the folder does not exist, it just creates a file and dumps all the files in that single file.
i.e 'find /log/traces -type f -mmin +59 -exec mv '{}' /Directory/User\;'
creates file named user and dumps all the files into that single file. I need to create folder with files of that hour. @mixiul__

Answer (score 0):

Does the directory `/Directory- (Timestamp)` exist before the script exist? I am guessing the directory is not there to move the files. Make sure the directory exists before you start moving.

You can create a shell script for moving the files that will take the target directory as a parameter along with the file name. Tf the target directory does not exist the script creates the directory. After that script will execute `mv` command to move the file to the target directory.